# Selecting a value for resistor to make initial capacitor voltage a certain amount

Tags: capacitor, short-circuit

[image]
In the above question, I found the amount of R1 to be 31.6k (R1 = 31.6KΩ) and I worked out R2 in this way:
`5 * (R1 / (R1 + R2)) * R2`  (first calculate the current in R2 branch and then use V = IR formula)
Which makes the `R2 = 0.40001`.

The book says that `v(0-) = 5R2` (somehow short-circuiting R1).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is the resistance of the inductor?

Comment: @BruceAbbott it's not mentioned.

Comment: Let's assume steady state before closing the switch: iC = 0A, uL = 0V

Because of uL = 0V, R1 is in parallel to R2.

Hence V0 =  5A * (R1 // R2)

I don't get the book's answer.